# extracting text from div of div without any attributes for all the divs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, findall

I am using this website:(https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/)
This is the area i am trying to scrape:

I am trying to scrape store name with their respective description.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=1"
data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(data.content,"html.parser")
shops=soup.find_all(class_="table table-hover")

for k in shops:
    name=[a.text for a in k.find_all("td")[0:2]]
    desc=k.find_all('div',class_='col-9')
    for q in desc:
    
        print(" ".join(name))
        print(q.text)
```

This is my output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNxL.png

As you can see from above, all the description are correct but then the shop name is wrong. Appreciate any help, thank you! :)

Comment: You're only setting `name` to the first 3 columns in the first row of the table. You're printing the same name for every description. Why don't you loop through the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the variable *name*, always it will be `['\n','\n','4 Fingers Crispy Chicken']`.

I would suggest change slightly your code to that:

```
shops=soup.find_all('div',class_="col-9")
names=soup.find_all('tr',class_="clickable")

for n, k in zip(names, shops):
 name = n.find_all('td')[1].text
 desc = k.text
 print(name + "\n")
 print(desc)
```

This manner will permit to iteract over the two variable simultaneously with the *zip* function. The *('td')[1]* uses the fact that the name of the store always stay on the second cell from the *tr* tag, with class *clickable*. If you get the *div* tag with class *col-9*, you just need take the text of that.